# Performance debugging with mmenu - how to build non-minified, non-obfuscated version

Tags: mmenu

How would I build (gulp) a version of mmenu that hasn't been minified and obfuscated - so that I can debug a performance issue? I'm finding that this call is taking roughly 1.5 seconds to run.

const mmenu = new Mmenu(mmenuId, options, config);

I'm assuming it is something related to the structure of our dom. Hoping by debugging in I can find a way to improve the structure and let mmenu have an easier time setting things up.

We are currently using version 8.5.6 of mmenu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

In this file:
/mmenu-js-master/gulp/js.js

I needed to uncomment the following lines (part of JSpack/webpack):
optimization: {
minimize: false
}

And then run the gulp build.